# xml parse from API response

Tags: python, xml, api, python-requests

There's an API that I am experimenting with that outputs XML.

Could anyone tell me if I have something wrong my code to parse the API response or is it a problem with the API itself?

I can use a `put` command with this:

```
import requests
import xml
from xml.etree import ElementTree

response = requests.post("https://openadrtester.herokuapp.com/api/v1/cpp/senorio/three")
string_xml = response.content
tree = xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring(string_xml)

xml.etree.ElementTree.dump(tree)
```

But it will error out on:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bbartling\OneDrive - Slipstream\Desktop\myAPI\tut\test.py", line 7, in <module>
    tree = xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring(string_xml)
  File "C:\Users\bbartling\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1315, in XML
    parser.feed(text)
  File "<string>", line None
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 0
```

XML is also viewable through the browser on a get request:

https://openadrtester.herokuapp.com/

Comment: What does `string_xml` contain if you `print()` it in your code?

Comment: b'{"notification": "True", "startTime": "2:00PM", "duration": "6 Hours", "randomization": "None", "rampUp": "None", "recovery": "None", "numberOfSignals": "2", "signalNameSimple": [{"signalType": "level", "units": "None", "numberOfIntervals": "None", "intervalDuration": "None", "typicalIntervalValues": "1,2,1", "signalTarget": "None"}], "signalNameElectricityPrice": [{"signalType": "price", "units": "USD per kWh", "numberOfIntervals": "3", "intervalDuration": "1 hour,4 hour,1 hour", "typicalIntervalValues": "$0.50,$0.75,$0.50", "signalTarget": "None"}]}\n'

Comment: That's json, not XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is not XML, but Json (parse it with `.json()` method, then access like normal python structure):

```
import json
import requests

response = requests.post("https://openadrtester.herokuapp.com/api/v1/cpp/senorio/three")
data = response.json()

print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Prints:

```
{
    "notification": "True",
    "startTime": "2:00PM",
    "duration": "6 Hours",
    "randomization": "None",
    "rampUp": "None",
    "recovery": "None",
    "numberOfSignals": "2",
    "signalNameSimple": [
        {
            "signalType": "level",
            "units": "None",
            "numberOfIntervals": "None",
            "intervalDuration": "None",
            "typicalIntervalValues": "1,2,1",
            "signalTarget": "None"
        }
    ],
    "signalNameElectricityPrice": [
        {
            "signalType": "price",
            "units": "USD per kWh",
            "numberOfIntervals": "3",
            "intervalDuration": "1 hour,4 hour,1 hour",
            "typicalIntervalValues": "$0.50,$0.75,$0.50",
            "signalTarget": "None"
        }
    ]
}
```

---

EDIT: To modify request header to obtain XML:

```
import requests

response = requests.post("https://openadrtester.herokuapp.com/api/v1/cpp/senorio/three", headers={'Accept': 'application/xml'})
print(response.text)
```

Prints:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><response><notification>True</notification><startTime>2:00PM</startTime><duration>6 Hours</duration><randomization>None</randomization><rampUp>None</rampUp><recovery>None</recovery><numberOfSignals>2</numberOfSignals><signalNameSimple><signalType>level</signalType><units>None</units><numberOfIntervals>None</numberOfIntervals><intervalDuration>None</intervalDuration><typicalIntervalValues>1,2,1</typicalIntervalValues><signalTarget>None</signalTarget></signalNameSimple><signalNameElectricityPrice><signalType>price</signalType><units>USD per kWh</units><numberOfIntervals>3</numberOfIntervals><intervalDuration>1 hour,4 hour,1 hour</intervalDuration><typicalIntervalValues>$0.50,$0.75,$0.50</typicalIntervalValues><signalTarget>None</signalTarget></signalNameElectricityPrice></response>
```

Comment: When people use like a `curl -i -H "Accept: application/xml"` is the `-H` a header arg?

Comment: If so Is it easy to modify my `requests` script for that?

Comment: Would there be any chance you could help me out with this one? :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64573932/flask-restful-output-xml-only